# Python Web scraping, Now I am keep getting StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a site.
I want to loop through all the dates in dateelements and if they match day than click on date, to select. collect the data and add it to the dataframe. I want to do it in one go as each day has unique data.

```
#Select the Display by splitting the data by AM/PM Split at 12 pm 
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'react-select-4--value- 
item')]").click()
Display = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'react-select- 
4--option-2')]").click()

######Select the date for scraping from the planning search calender
browser.find_element_by_id("room-planning-from-date").click()
planning_From_Dates = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//* 
[contains(@class,'DayPicker-Day')]")


for dateelements in itertools.islice(planning_From_Dates,None,None,n):
date = dateelements.text
  for day in days:
     time.sleep(0.1)
     print('This is the date:',date,'| This is the day',day)
     if date == day:
         dateelements.click()
         time.sleep(3)
         child_groups =browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//* 
         [contains(@class,'roomPlanning__attendanceInfoHeader')]")
         for group in child_groups:
            #time.sleep(0.2)
            Group = group.text
            group.click()
            #Lets bring the page source into the tool make sure we have 
            the correct page
            page = browser.page_source
            dfs = pd.read_html(page, header = 0)
            df = dfs[0]
            ##Add dfs together
```

Comment: To repeat and better understand your issue provide code example, not screenshot.

Comment: Thanks, I have update the question might have indentation errors.

Comment: Provide full code to reproduce: imports, URLs, initiation phase.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not do that. It's kinda confidential. The problem I am having is at date = dateelements.text. The code will loop through once and throw out an exception